# Stuck...Stuck and stuck how do I overcome it?

Tags: creative-writing, novel, writers-block

I've been writing since I was little but despite the idea I've had for over a year I still haven't completed it. I'm feeling stuck but I know I have something to say with my writing. Someone on a group I follow about writing had once said that if I couldn't write then I didn't have anything to say but I don't think it's like that which is making it more frustrating. I know I can write, and I've written before, many times, but I'm stuck. How do you get unstuck on writing? I've thought it could be because a mental block of some kind but I'm not sure. How have you overcome being stuck and wanting to write but it never coming out?